# What will be the time and space complexity for vertical order traversal of a binary tree?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, binary-tree

I have written the following c++ function to traverse a binary tree in vertical order. For nodes on the same vertical level, I want to store them in the order they will appear in the level order traversal.

Example: If we have the tree like this:

```
    1
  /   \
 2     3
/ \   /  \
4  5 6   7
```

I want to return a vector of vectors as:

```
{
{4}
{2}
{1 5 6}
{3}
{7}
}
```

```
void traversal(TreeNode* node, int x, int y, map<int,map<int,vector<int>>> &m){
    if(node == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if(m[x].find(y) == m[x].end()){
        vector<int> temp;
        m[x][y] = temp;
    }
    m[x][y].push_back(node->val);
    traversal(node->left,x-1,y+1,m);
    traversal(node->right,x+1,y+1,m);
    return;
    
} 
vector<vector<int>> verticalOrderTraversal(TreeNode* A) {
    map<int,map<int,vector<int>>> m;
    traversal(A,0,0,m);
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    for(auto itr:m){
        vector<int> temp;
        for(auto itr2:itr.second){
            for(auto i:itr2.second){
                temp.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        ans.push_back(temp);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

How do I calculate its time complexity and space complexity in big O notation?

I read somewhere that the optimized code is of O(NlogN) time complexity. But it uses level order traversal. How do I calculate time complexity for my code that uses pre-order traversal?

Comment: The result looks like a vector of vectors. I'm not sure how `y` factors in, nor why you're using `map`s

Comment: Not answering the question, but I simplified the code. Turns out a map makes handling the negative `x` easier, so I see why you did that. coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc2bbe577364e3af

Comment: @Mooing Duck Thanks for the simplified code. Answering your question about `y`, I am using it for storing the depth of the nodes. I want to store the nodes on the same vertical level, in increasing order of their depth ( i.e. in their level-order traversal).

For example, modifying the above tree so that the `5th` node has a right child `8`, I want to store `{3, 8}`. If I don't maintain the depth, it will store `{8, 3}` instead, since I am using pre-order traversal.

I have now realized that had I used level-order traversal instead, I wouldn't have to do all this extra work.

Answer (score 2):

**Time Complexity**

The traversal function is called *recursively* for each node in the binary tree, which gives us a worst-case time complexity of `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of nodes in the tree. The function will create *function call* `(N)` number of stack frames. (I am not aware of any software or website where I could "sketch" or "graph" a recursion tree)

Here is my best effort of making a recursion tree in plain text:

```
traversal(node, x, y, m)
    |
    |--- traversal(node->left, x-1, y+1, m)
    |       |
    |       |--- traversal(node->left->left, x-2, y+2, m)
    |       |       |
    |       |       |--- (leaf node)
    |       |
    |       |--- traversal(node->left->right, x-2, y+2, m)
    |               |
    |               |--- (leaf node)
    |
    |--- traversal(node->right, x+1, y+1, m)
            |
            |--- traversal(node->right->left, x, y+2, m)
            |       |
            |       |--- (leaf node)
            |
            |--- traversal(node->right->right, x+2, y+2, m)
                    |
                    |--- (leaf node)

//continues depending on the size of your tree
```

I think this is kinda self-explanatory, assuming you are taking Data Structures and are familiar with `BST`'s. Each parent potentially has 2 children or less. Each recursive call "walks" the tree until it reaches a `nullptr` or a non-existing child.

Side note: You should use [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) instead of `NULL` due to type safety, readability and overload ambiguity.

This goes for all traversals such as (in-, pre-, and post-) since you have to visit every node and either print or store it...

Your recursive call:

```
    traversal(node->left,x-1,y+1,m);
    traversal(node->right,x+1,y+1,m);
```

Within the traversal function, most of the operations performed are constant time operations, except:

Checking if a key exists in the map `(m[x].find(y))` takes `O(log M)`, where `M` is the number of unique vertical levels encountered so far. However, since `M` is *proportional* to the number of nodes `N` in the tree, we can just say its big O is `O(log(N))`.

**Why is map.find() `O(log(N))`?**

`std::map` is implemented with a **balanced BST**, therefore searching an element requires `O(log(N))`, since we are "splitting" the tree in half every iteration.

Therefore we get `N * log(N)` which can be simplified to **`O(Nlog(N))`**.

Your `verticalOrderTraversal` calls the recursive function, hence `O(Nlog(N))`, but it also uses 3 nested `for` loops to construct your `std::vector`. As mentioned in the comments, the number of iterations will always be `N` therefore (again, looking at the worst case) we have

```
T(N) = NlogN + N

//T(n) is defined as C*f(N) where f(N) is the bigO and C is a constant
```

we raise everything to the highest power and we get `T(N) = 1*NlogN` hence the time complexity of your vertical order traversal is `O(Nlon(N))`.

**Space Complexity**

As mentioned in the comments:

The `std::map m` stores the nodes based on their vertical `V` and horizontal `H` positions. The space required for `m` depends on the number of unique vertical positions (x values) and the number of unique horizontal positions (y values). In the worst case, where all nodes have distinct positions, the space complexity is `O(N)`.

The answer `std::vector ans` stores the vectors of node values. Each node value is stored once in the map and then copied to the answer vector. Therefore, the space required for `ans` is also `O(N)` in the worst case.

As discussed above, the space used by the recursive calls in the `traversal` function depends on the height of the binary tree `H`. In the worst case, where the tree is skewed/[degenerate](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ethornton/ics46/Notes/BinarySearchTrees/#:%7E:text=A%20degenerate%20tree%20is%20one,have%20to%20visit%20every%20node.) and has a height of `N`, the space complexity due to the recursive stack would then be `O(N)`. However, when we look at a balanced tree, the maximum height would be `log N`, resulting in `O(log N)` space complexity.

```
T(N) = N + N + logN
T(N) = 3N

//T(n) = C*f(N)
//C = 3
//f(N) = O(N)
```

To conclude the space complexity of your code is `O(N)`.

Comment: I agree, but the question was about analyzing the time and space complexity rather than optimizing the code.

Comment: Also: I disagree with your analysis: `traversal` accesses each node once, and calls `map.find` once per node, which makes it `O(Nlog(N))` to iterate the whole graph, not `O(N)`.  And despite the fact that `verticalOrderTraversal` uses three nested loops, the *total number of iterations* is always exactly `N`, which makes those loops `O(N)`.

Comment: Similarly, the data structures never hold more than `N` elements, even accounting for recursion, making space complexity `O(N)` as well. You've overthought this.

Comment: Wouldn't the map need `n^3` space?

Comment: Each `value` is in the map exactly once, so if you think of it as one giant data structure, it's clearly `O(N)`, plus whatever overhead is needed by that data structure. That overhead is large, but it's all proportional to the data they each hold, which means the overhead is all constant factors.

Comment: In `traversal` function, why are we not considering search operations i.e `m[x][y].push_back(node->val)` for time complexity? Also how do we get `m[x].find(y)` as O(logN)? In `map<int,int>`, `.find()` take O(logN) time. How do we calculate time complexity for a nested map `map<int,map<int,int>>`?

Comment: @s72r69y I would suggest you look at the documentation of certain methods defined in libraries, for instance `push_back()` takes constant time `O(1)` in the `vector` library that's why we don't care about that. As for why is `std::map` `O(logN)` please read the answer again... "*How do we calculate time complexity for a nested map `map<int,map<int,int>>?`*" I would suggest going back to your books. Declarations don't affect time complexity...

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian I know `push_back()` takes O(1) time, but I am asking about `m[x][y].push_back()`. We are searching firstly for `m[x]` in the map and then `m[x][y]` inside it. How do we know it will be a O(1) operation? Also, please share if you have any resources for "_Declarations don't affect time complexity_".